# Tutorial for creating a landing page imitating the subscription center

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I am looking for a detailed tutorial for building landing pages for users to opt-in and out of communications, including the publication lists. This pages should almost imitate the behavior of the subscription center in emails. But the link to this subscription center is apparently not that straightforward to generate from outside the email. Also, we would like to offer users the chance to opt back in and continue receiving communications.

Is there a place I can look into? The Trailblazer Community seems to take many things for granted and skips many necessary details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Create a Custom Profile Center with AMPscript

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!